# Simplify binomial coefficient

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

I have the following equation
$$
\frac{\sum_{i=0}^t \binom{s-1+w+i}{s-1}}{\sum_{i=0}^t \binom{s-1+i}{s-1}}
$$
with $ s,w,t $ greater or equal zero.

I want to simplify this equation as much as possible. Can you help me?

Comment: for your numerator i have got $${\frac { \left( w+t+1 \right)  \left( s+w+t \right) !}{s \left( s-1
 \right) !\, \left( w+t+1 \right) !}}-{\frac {w \left( s+w-1 \right) !
}{s \left( s-1 \right) !\,w!}}
$$

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! I would be happy, if you could give me some hints how you got to the result for the numerator, since I would like to be able to explain that simplification.

Comment: try to simplify the summands of your sum and consider the partial sum

Comment: and for your denominator we get $${\frac { \left( t+1 \right)  \left( s+t \right) !}{s \left( s-1
 \right) !\, \left( t+1 \right) !}}
$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am a merchant, with various goods. I have $s$ Stuffs, $w-1$ Wares, and $t+1$ Things. I want to pick $s$ of them, but I want to ensure that there is at least one Thing among them. In how many ways can I do this?

Counting Method 1: The total ways to pick $s$ goods without restrictions is $\binom{s+w-1+t+1}{s}$, and the total ways to pick $s$ goods just from my Stuffs and Wares is $\binom{s+w-1}{s}$, so I get $\binom{s+w-1+t+1}{s}-\binom{s+w-1}{s}.$

Counting Method 2: My Things are ordered from most special to least special. If I want the most special Thing to be in this selection, then I have $\binom{s+w-1+t}{s-1}$ ways to choose the remaining goods. If I do not, but I do want my second most special Thing to be in this selection, then I have $\binom{s+w-1+t-1}{s-1}$ ways to choose the remaining goods, and similarly if I do not want my $i$ most special Things to be in this selection. But if I get to the least special Thing, then I have to include it, and I have $\binom{s+w-1}{s-1}$ ways to pick the remaining goods from my Stuffs and Wares. Thus, I have $\sum_{i=0}^{t}\binom{s+w-1+i}{s-1}$ ways to make this selection. (And if you were worried about the order, just consider this: for any selection, there must be a most special Thing contained, so somewhere in this procedure, I will count it. Thus, I really do count every possible selection.)

Since these count the same thing, they must be equal, so $$\sum_{i=0}^{t}\binom{s+w-1+i}{s-1}=\binom{s+w+t}{s}-\binom{s+w-1}{s}.$$

A similar argument can be made to show that $\sum_{i=0}^{t}\binom{s-1+i}{s-1}=\binom{s+t}{s},$ with just $s-1$ Stuffs and $t+1$ Things, and no restrictions on the selection.

By the way, I don't mean to make this sound silly... I just think it's much easier to keep track of "Stuffs, Wares, and Things" than it is to keep track of "elements of sets 1, 2, and 3," especially with the choice of variables.

Comment: Thank your for your visual answer. But I have a little understanding problem in the 2nd count method. When you say "If I want the most special Thing to be in this selection, then I have....", do you mean, that we put the "t+1"-th Thing (the most special one) in our selection, and have only t Things left for our remaining selection and so on?

How can we be sure that both count methods counts the same?

Comment: I mean that the most special Thing is either in the selection, or it is not. The first case is counted as $\binom{s+w-1+t}{s-1}$, and everything else is the second case. To count the second case, I repeat that argument, so if the most special Thing is not in the selection, the second most special Thing is either in the selection, or not, and so forth.

Comment: We can be sure they count the same quantity, because any valid selection has at least one Thing, and therefore there is a most special Thing among the Things in the selection, call this mint, say. At the step in the process above where we say "either mint is in the selection, or it is not," we would then count this selection, as part of the case where mint is in the selection.

Comment: If it's easier, just call the Things $1,\ldots,t+1,$ and instead of "most special," say "greatest." $t+1$ is in the set, or it is not. Proceeding down from the top, we see that at some point, we must arrive at the greatest element of $\{1,\ldots,t+1\}$ that belongs to our selection, at which point we are sure to count that selection.

Comment: Thank you, I understand it better now. I have a last question about the denominator term. You say, that we have only s-1 STUFFS and t+1 THINGS now. And now we want to pick s out of all goods without restrictions. Now I try to establish the second count method. I order the THINGS from the most to the least special. Do I say that the most special THING can't be in our selection and therefore there are $\binom{s-1+t}{s-1}$ ways to pick? Then do I say that the most and second most special THING can't be in our selection and there are $\binom{s-1+t-1}{s-1}$ ways to pick and so on?

Comment: Almost, but the first case is that the most special Thing is in the selection, so you have to select the remaining $s-1$ goods from the other $s-1+t$ items. The second term is when the most special Thing is not in the selection, but the second most special Thing is, and so on. The last term is $\binom{s-1}{s-1},$ the case where there is no Thing in the selection.

Comment: But I thought, there are no restrictions on the selection. But now you say, that the most special thing is in the selection and then the second special thing but not the most special thing and so on. So is this not the same restriction on the selection like in the nominator term?

Comment: In the numerator, the restriction is that there is at least one Thing. In the denominator, this restriction is lifted.